# preventing Activity from doing something in background

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-activity

I got the following scenario:
I am writing an app, which acts like a chat client. It connects to server on start and is listening for messages (the network things are handled by a service).
My problem is a few seconds after signing off (the concerning method sends a signal to the server and then stops the service and calling finish()), the app seem to sign on again without doing anything (i can see this in the server logs). I am not sure how to handle this problem, what i mean is preventing my app signing on again in background. 
The sign on method gets invoked by the service which is created in the onCreate method of my main activity. I am not very familiar yet with android and i hope anybody can give me a hint.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
sMau

Edit for code adding:
And i recognized in logcat i get a message like "scheduling restart of crashed service in xxxx ms"
The initNetwork method and the timer class are shortened, there is only the very much network stuff id dont want to be executed automatically due to a auto service restart.

```
public class NetworkService extends Service {

public static String path;
static ClientUserConfig myConfig;
private ChatKeys keys;

static Frontend_CS front_cs;
static Frontend_CK front_ck;

public static Boolean runOnce = true;

private String server_ip = "10.0.2.2"; 

private static PPAClientActivity MAIN_ACTIVITY;
private int serverConnectionTimer;

private HashedWheelTimer timer;

private final LinkedList<String> chatWindows = new LinkedList<String>();


class TimedChecksAndroid implements TimerTask {

        public void run(Timeout tmt) {
            String senderEmail;
            String senderFullname;
            LinkedList<String> list;
            int selection;
            int chatNum;

            ClientUserEntry user;

            if (serverConnectionTimer>=60){



}





@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();


    shutdownService();

    if (MAIN_ACTIVITY != null) {
        MAIN_ACTIVITY.showMessages(Consts.SERVICE_STOPPED);
    }
}

private void shutdownService() {

    Log.d("SERVICENET", "Shutdown reached.");

    if(NetworkService.front_cs.getServer_handler() != null) {
        Log.d("SERVICENET", "IF Block Sign OFF reached.");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add(NetworkService.myConfig.getEmail());
        NetworkService.front_cs.getServer_handler().sendMessage(new UniversalContainerMessage(ppa.utils.Constants.CS_GOING_OFFLINE_OPCODE,list));
    }

}
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.d("SERVICENET", "Service creation started.");

    super.onCreate();

    path = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/"; // TODO erzeugt manchmal nullpointer?


    initNetwork();

    if (MAIN_ACTIVITY != null) {
        MAIN_ACTIVITY.showMessages(Consts.SERVICE_STARTED);
    }

}



private void initNetwork() {

    String fullname = null;
    String email = null;
    boolean cfgBuildSuccess = true;



    serverConnectionTimer = 0;
    timer = new HashedWheelTimer();
    timer.newTimeout(new TimedChecksAndroid(), ppa.utils.Constants.CHATCLIENT_CHECK_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //schedular = new SchedularDialog(this, false, myConfig, front_cs);

}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public static void setMainActivity(PPAClientActivity activity) {
      MAIN_ACTIVITY = activity;
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you use any broadcast reciever that launches the service?

Comment: It is far more likely that we are able to help you out if you post the code from your activity, and service ;-)

Comment: I edited my post and added the important code parts, but if somethin is missing please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to start/stop a service.

1. Service started with `Context.startService()`. To stop such a service your activity should call `stopService()` or the service itself should call `stopSelf()`.
2. Service started with `Context.bindService()`. To stop a bound service **ALL** your activities that called `bindService()` should call `unbindService()`.

When you start a service via method 1 the `onStartCommand()` method in your service will be called and since you don't have that I'm assuming that you are using the 2nd method. If this is the case, my guess would be that either not all your activities called `unbindService()` or there is an activity that has called `bindService` after the service was stopped.

You might want to check the [Service API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for an example how to start/stop a service.